# Fill in a box on page within WebView from XCode

Tags: xcode, xcode3.2

I am looking at doing an app which contains a webview that points to a website that requires a  login.  I know how to do the webview, etc., but is there a way that I can automatically fill in the usernanme and password through XCode?  I am looking at storing the user name and password within the iPhone's data (any advice on that would be appreciated!), filling in the username, password, and clicking the login button.

I will know the names of these boxes if that helps?

Answer (score 0):

Try using UIWebView's -stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString: method. Create a javascript snippet to fill your fields, and then evaluate it after your web page is loaded.